How to position lines in the y-axis closer to each other
The data is:
df <- structure(list(vec = c("PC", "DEFAULT", "INFORMED"), mean = c(1.34944359241928, 
                                                          1.36249329506777, 1.34671188869646), sd = c(0.57779881866326, 
                                                                                                      0.537279303541924, 1.53585580464849), min = c(0.196903771571785, 
                                                                                                                                                    0.28781509871908, -1.66860228474139), `0.5quant` = c(1.35295469982876, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         1.36643973099316, 1.34687516700723), max = c(2.48177705326348, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.41483607230639, 4.36109982194179), mode = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    NA_real_), kld = c(1.9807860333589e-08, 2.97333113261951e-08, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       3.91753938449056e-10), ID = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

Which I want to plot as:
yaxis <- c("Ppppppppp ppppppp 
pppp pp pppppp 
(ppp)", "Uuuuuuuuu uuuuu", "Iiiiiii iiiii 
       ii Iiiiii (iiii)")

myplot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mean, y = ID)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), height = .1) + geom_vline (xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-4,4.5,0.5)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = yaxis)


My questions are the following:

I want to reduce the distance between 'i', 'u' and 'p' in the y-axis: in other words, the white lines have to be gone (correspondingly I crossed them out in the graph with a red marker), and three black lines (credible/confidence intervals) have to be positioned closer in the y-axis.

I want to center the text in the labels in the y-axis (I circled them with a blue marker). In other words, the text in each label has to be centered.


Guys, could you help me out with this?

Convert the variable mapped on y to a factor and center the the axis text using hjust= .5. Additionally I added linebreaks "\n" to break the labels into multiple lines.
library(ggplot2)

yaxis <- c(
  "Ppppppppp ppppppp\npppp pp pppppp\n(ppp)",
  "Uuuuuuuuu uuuuu",
  "Iiiiiii iiiii\nii Iiiiii (iiii)"
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = mean, y = factor(ID))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = min, xmax = max), height = .1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-4, 4.5, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = yaxis) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = .5))



Gah!  Beat me to it by a few seconds...

That is great! But do you think it is possible to position 3 black lines even closer to each other?

Sure. You can increase the expansion of the y scale, e.g. try + scale_y_discrete(labels = yaxis, expand = expansion(add = 2)). This will of course add some additional space at the top and bottom.
